# How is "と" being used in these two sentences: 「ふりむくと、こどもたちが...」「トンネルをつくろうっと。」

Tags: particle-と

I think "と" is being used differently in both of these sentences. However, I'm not entirely sure if it is being used as a particle in either one. Can you please explain to me the purpose of "と" in these sentences and how it changes the meaning of the sentences?

> 1. ふりむく**と**、こどもたちが　おおきな　やまを　つくっています。
> 2. ぼく、トンネルを　つくろうっ**と**。

Answer (score 8, accepted):

「と」 is used as a particle in both cases.

> 1.「ふりむく**と**、こどもたちが　おおきな　やまを　つくっています。」

Here, the 「と」 is a ***conjunctive particle*** meaning "when" as in "When I did A, I saw B happening."

The sentence means "***When I turned around, the kids were making a huge mountain***."

The tense used in the original is the present, but it is the historical present, which is why I used the past tense in my translation.

> 2.「ぼく、トンネルを　つくろう**っと**。」

The 「っと」 here is the ***quotative particle***, believe it or not.  The speaker is quoting himself, so to speak.

「Verb in volitional form + っと」 is a ***very*** common structure used in colloquial conversations.  It is a way of making a ***light and casual declaration*** (more to oneself than to others).  With this 「っと」, the speaker is often just thinking out loud.

***"Alright, let's dig a tunnel here!"*** (Said more to oneself than to another.)

Comment: Can you use the "と" as a conjunctive particle to mean "when" after any verb at the beginning of a sentence like the first one? How were you able to tell that the first sentence was written in the "historical present"?